# How could mapfile hang indefinitely?

Tags: linux, bash

The following bash command:

```
mapfile -t "DP_ARGS" "<${ARG_PATH}"
```

Hang indefinitely, why?

Comment: As an aside, all-caps variables are in space reserved for use by POSIX-defined utilities (including the shell itself); your scripts should use names with at least one lower-case character for variables they define themselves to overwriting content in this namespace accidentally. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html defining naming conventions for environment variables -- read it keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By quoting `"<${ARG_PATH}"` you are passing an unused argument to `mapfile` instead of redirecting. It therefore hangs waiting for you to enter data via keyboard instead.

To redirect, leave `<` unquoted:

```
mapfile -t "DP_ARGS" < "${ARG_PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sounds like a design flaw in bash

Comment: @tribbloid, the only way it's a flaw is that `mapfile` probably ought to throw an error when unused arguments are present (and if you emailed the `bash-bug` mailing list, I'd hazard the next version would probably end up doing that). Every other aspect of this behavior is completely in line with documentation / spec -- `"<foo"` isn't **supposed** to be identical to `<"foo"`; if it were, you couldn't pass arguments with `<` as a first character (so a design where your original code worked as you intend would be a much _worse_ design than the present one).

Comment: bash shouldn't hang in any case (unless it is a deadloop), it should at least give a prompt for more input

Comment: This should also apply to all command-line interfaces

Comment: @tribbloid, it's not a "hang", it's doing something useful: reading input from stdin (which right now points to your terminal) to the array. If you have a script that runs `mapfile -t stdin_lines` and pipe something to its input, you want that input to go to `stdin_lines`, right? And if you run that script by hand and type input on stdin (pressing ctrl+d when it's done), you probably want _that_ input you typed by hand to _also_ go into `stdin_lines`, right? So how is the interpreter supposed to detect when the behavior _isn't_ wanted, if there are perfectly normal cases where it's desirable?

Comment: @tribbloid, ...I could see making a coherent argument that programs _shouldn't_ have stdin attached to the TTY by default -- that it should be `/dev/null` by default unless something else is explicitly requested -- but that was a decision made back in the 1970s, and then codified into industry standards in the 1990s; you can't change it today without breaking compatibility with literally decades of system behavior / expectations / documentation / textbooks / etc. And even then, I'm not sure it's a _good_ idea, just that it's possible to argue for.

Comment: @tribbloid, ...re: "prompt for more input", often that's not desirable. If you run `readarray array <file`, you don't expect a `> ` to be printed every time it's ready to read a line, right? -- so you'd need to be adding (yet another) change in default behavior between tty and non-tty cases, and all such conditionals are sources of confusion. Similarly, `read` doesn't print a prompt unless passed `-p`, and it would be a breaking change to make it do so now, causing scripts that print their own prompts to then have double prompts printed.

Comment: @tribbloid, ...part of the thing to keep in mind that this isn't "command-line-interface" behavior, it's _inter-process communication_ behavior. stdin isn't just used for communicating with the user on a terminal; it's used for communications between programs. Making `cat` and `awk` and `grep` and `sed` and every other program that could ever read from stdin do the work to test whether they're currently reading from a tty and print prompts to stderr if it is is distributing a _lot_ of responsibility to a _lot_ of different places. This isn't a problem that could be changed just by fixing bash

Comment: ...but rather requires _every program bash starts that could read from stdin_ to also be changed. That's simply not a reasonable ask -- it's much simpler and saner to treat it as a user-education problem.